# Definition of Variable

Tags: definition

In mathematics, what is a variable?  I have encountered previous definitions stating that it is a symbol representing an element of a set or a placeholder for an unknown value. However, I have been unable to understand these definitions. Please provide some simple definitions.

Comment: See [What is the formal definition of a variable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/744614/what-is-the-formal-definition-of-a-variable) as well as [A formal definition of a variable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1703442/a-formal-definition-of-a-variable).

Comment: A [Variable (in mathematics)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_(mathematics)) is a *symbol*.

Comment: Quite often the *understanding of a definition* comes later if you study math material that applies that definition.

Comment: A symbol that represents a currently unknown value and is **able** to **vary**.