# Formal definition of "dependent variable"

Tags: terminology

There are similar questions [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1703442/a-formal-definition-of-a-variable) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/744614/what-is-the-formal-definition-of-a-variable) asking about a "formal definition of a variable", but the "dependent" makes this unique. If you search the web for "dependent variable" you get hit with things saying,

> "In the case $y=f(x)$, $y$ is the dependent variable, $f$ is the function, and $x$ is the
> independent variable."

Can we formally call $y$ a variable?

I realize this question is digging in the weeds and people often understand what is meant in context. However, formally, is it wrong to call $y$ a variable?

### EDIT

I found an old chat session I had. Granted I was asking about functions, the response I got applies here. I think it helps support my curiosity

> People who write "y = f(x)" are typically not doing rigorous mathematics. It is unfortunate that historically people started adopting a convention where a relationship between varying quantities in a physical setting is depicted with x being a so-called independent variable (more like a manipulated variable) and y being a dependent variable (more like an observed variable), and if a functional relation is suspected then people would write y = f(x).
> But that was done long before mathematical functions were made rigorous. Sadly, old habits die hard.
> The correct way to express such things in modern mathematics is as follows.
> Suppose you have a function f : R→R. Then you can plot the graph of f in the plane by plotting the set of points { (x,y) : y = f(x) }. The graph of f is not f itself, but merely one way to represent f.
> We can call this graph the graph of f(x) against x, or the graph of y against x where y = f(x).
> Either phrasing would be completely unambiguous and rigorous, and correspond to the definition of "graph" as given above.

Comment: A variable is dependent if it is completely defined by other variables. The only way to determine what is and isn't a variable is context.

Comment: Along with the above,  if we are given $y=f(x)$, we know we can determine $y$ uniquely from $x$.   If $f$ happens to be an injection (one to one),  then we can also determine $x$ given $y$,  taking $y$ from range($f$)

Comment: "People who write "y = f(x)" are typically not doing rigorous mathematics." That's nonsense.

Comment: @JairTaylor It depends on how rigorous is rigorous. People doing formal logic don't write that, as far as I know.

Comment: @JairTaylor Also, if you write $y = f(x)$ then you are saying $y$ is a constant (indeed, the value of the function $f$ at the point $x$ of its domain) and then treat $y$ like a "function" is plain, untasteful, nasty, bad maths in my opion.

Comment: Only terminology... $x$ is the variable and $f$ is the function. Writing $y=f(x)$ we are simply "renaming" function $f$.

Comment: @WillM. Just by writing $y=f(x)$ it's not implied that $y$ is a function.  It's often written to mean exactly that $y=f(x)$ for a particular $x$.

Furthermore, when you do write $y=f(x)$ in the sense that $y$ is a function, this is just shorthand for talking about the function $f$ in a notationally convenient way. It's no more or less rigorous than other kinds of common "abuse of notation".

Comment: The writing $y=f(x)$ is simply due to historical reasons: in the cartesian-coordinates graph we plot $F(x)$ on the $y$-axes. It is simply the graph of function $f$.

Comment: @OP You may as well always write "depedent variable" and "independent variable" since these terms cannot be formally defined and are just a mental trick to follow arguments. Of course, always writing the quotation marks will be utterly pedantic.

Answer (score 1):

A variable is a quantity that varies (over a set of its possible values). Here, as $x$ varies over the domain of the function $f,$ $y$ correspondingly varies over the range of $f.$ Since the value of $y$ is completely determined by the value of $x$ and the mapping operation $f, y$ is variable that depends on $x.$ (To be clear: variable $y$ stands for the value/output of the function $f.$)

Framed this way, $x$ is the independent variable and $y$ the dependent variable.

On the other hand, $y=x^3,$ for example, can be rewritten as $x=y^\frac13$ to discuss instead the behaviour of $x$ as $y$ is varies; in this case, $y$ becomes the independent variable, and $x$ the dependent variable.

Comment: On the other hand, if the dependent variable $y$ had been experimentally determined by varying the independent variable $x,$ then reflecting the plotted curve in the line $y=x$ does not necessarily give the graph of $x$ (now the dependent variable) as $y$ (now the independent variable) varies; this is because $y$ may not be an injective function of $x.$